# As the best way to draw this diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, timing-diagrams

As the best way to draw this diagram?

[image]

See a MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5cm]
\draw[black,->,thick,>=latex]
  (0,0) -- ++(5.5,0) node[above right] {$t$};
\draw[black,thick]
  (0,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node[above] {4000\,BC};
\draw[black,thick]
  (1,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node[above] {1800};
\draw[black,thick]
  (2,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node[above] {1960};
\draw[black,thick]
  (3,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node[above] {1980};
\draw[black,thick]
  (4,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node[above] {2000};
%
\node[above right] at (-0.05,-0.8cm) {Manual Processing -- paper and pancil};
\node[above right] at (0.9,-1.3cm) {Mechanical -- punched card};
\node[above right] at (1.8,-1.8cm) {Stored Program -- sequential record processing};
\node[above right] at (2.5,-2.3cm) {Online -- navigational set processing};
\node[above right] at (3.1,-2.8cm) {Non-Procedural -- relational};
\node[above right] at (3.6,-3.3cm) {Multi-Media -- internetwork};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: To add outline and color use, for example, \node[draw=black,fill=green!25,above right] at (-0.05,-0.8cm) {Manual Processing -- paper and pancil};

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how precisely you want to follow the image. (For example, you've added an arrow and tic markers and *t* which are not in the image you posted....)

This is something of a compromise. It retains some aspects of the close spacing (lines very close to the tops of the lettering in the nodes) but keeps the tics and the arrowed timeline *t* since I assume you wouldn't have added them if you didn't want them.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    x=2cm,
    epoch line/.append style={draw, ultra thick, black},
    font=\bfseries,
    year/.append style={font=\sffamily\bfseries},
  ]
  \draw[black,->,thick,>=latex]
    (0,0) -- ++(5.5,0) node[above right] {$t$};
  \draw[black,thick]
    (0,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node (4000bce) [above, year] {4000\,BCE};
  \draw[black,thick]
    (1,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node (1800) [above, year] {1800};
  \draw[black,thick]
    (2,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node (1960) [above, year] {1960};
  \draw[black,thick]
    (3,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node (1980) [above, year] {1980};
  \draw[black,thick]
    (4,0) -- ++(0,5pt) node (2000) [above, year] {2000};
  %
  \node (pap) [above right] at (-0.05,-0.8cm) {Manual Processing -- paper and pencil};
  \node (pc) [above right, inner xsep=.1em] at (0.9,-1.3cm) {Mechanical -- punched card};
  \node (srp) [above right, inner xsep=.1em] at (1.8,-1.8cm) {Stored Program -- sequential record processing};
  \node (nsp) [above right, inner xsep=.1em] at (2.5,-2.3cm) {Online -- navigational set processing};
  \node (reln) [above right, inner xsep=.1em] at (3.1,-2.8cm) {Non-Procedural -- relational};
  \node (inet) [above right, inner xsep=.1em] at (3.6,-3.3cm) {Multi-Media -- internetwork};
  \path [epoch line] (pap.north -| 4000bce) -- (5,0 |- pap.north);
  \path [epoch line] (pap.south -| 4000bce) -- (5,0 |- pap.south);
  \path [epoch line] (pc.south west) -- (5,0 |- pc.south);
  \path [epoch line] (srp.south west) -- (5,0 |- srp.south);
  \path [epoch line] (nsp.south west) -- (5,0 |- nsp.south);
  \path [epoch line] (reln.south west) -- (5,0 |- reln.south);
  \path [epoch line] (inet.south west) -- (5,0 |- inet.south);
  \path [epoch line] (pc.south west |- pap.south) -- (pc.south west);
  \path [epoch line] (srp.south west |- pc.south) -- (srp.south west);
  \path [epoch line] (nsp.south west |- srp.south) -- (nsp.south west);
  \path [epoch line] (reln.south west |- nsp.south) -- (reln.south west);
  \path [epoch line] (inet.south west |- reln.south) -- (inet.south west);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill [left color=red!60!white, right color=white] (inet.north west) -- (5,0 |- inet.north) -- (5,0 |- inet.south) -- (inet.south west) -- cycle;
    \fill [left color=orange!60!white, right color=white] (reln.north west) -- (5,0 |- reln.north) -- (5,0 |- reln.south) -- (reln.south west) -- cycle;
    \fill [left color=magenta!60!white, right color=white] (nsp.north west) -- (5,0 |- nsp.north) -- (5,0 |- nsp.south) -- (nsp.south west) -- cycle;
    \fill [left color=blue!60!white, right color=white] (srp.north west) -- (5,0 |- srp.north) -- (5,0 |- srp.south) -- (srp.south west) -- cycle;
    \fill [left color=blue!60!green!60!white, right color=white] (pc.north west) -- (1980 |- pc.north) -- (1980 |- pc.south) -- (pc.south west) -- cycle;
    \fill [fill=white] (1980 |- pc.north) -- (5,0 |- pc.north) -- (5,0 |- pc.south) -- (1980 |- pc.south) -- cycle;
    \fill [left color=white, right color=green!70!blue!60!white] (pap.north -| 4000bce) -- (5,0 |- pap.north) -- (5,0 |- pap.south) -- (pap.south -| 4000bce) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Doubtless there are better methods...

[image: Coloured timeline]

Comment: @Youra_P The customary way to say thank you on this site is to accept the answer which helps you the most and/or to upvote however many answers you find useful. But you should wait a couple of days before accepting anything, I believe.